# VIM How Can I Force VIM to Arrange Words According to My Choice?

Tags: vim, indentation

Well I am writing and learning. I just want to write some text in this way....

```
- First line.
  Second line.
  Third line.
```

But the problem is the lines are starting in this way...

```
- First line.
Second line.
Third line
```

You see the difference? Well I did some research and found a thread in superuser which recommends to use :set smartindent. I did so. It's working. But the problem is this actually force Vim to follow from where last line is started. Now as I am starting lines from left hand edge of the editor so Vim is starting every new line as shown in second example. Now the question is how can I write lines as I showed in first example?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect the editor to always choose the right indent? By configuring a particular *indent* setting (like the good and universal `:set smartindent`), you get something that works most of the time. For those other cases, you can always indent manually (with `<Tab>`, assuming you've properly `:set tabstop=... expandtab` etc.), or change the indent after the fact with `>>` and `<<`.

If you really have a particular syntax where the indenting rules are rather simple and deterministic (and none of the default indent settings work all the time), you have to write a custom `indentexpr` (cp. `:help indent-expression`).

As your example is about text formatting, I don't this applies, and you're really better of with `'smartindent'` and manual corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'smartindent', I'd rather set 'autoindent', 'formatlistpat', and 'formatoptions' appropriately. For example:

```
" set up pattern to match list bullets and numbers
let &l:formatlistpat='^\s*\%(\d\+[\]:.)}\t ]\d\@!\|[*-]\)\s*'
" automatically format numbered or bulleted lists
setlocal formatoptions+=n
setlocal autoindent
```

In the first command, you can substitute whatever "bullet" characters you like inside the `[*-]` group.

This will keep the indent for you, and will even apply it for you with `gqip` for example, but you will need to remove the indent by yourself when you enter a new line you want to not have the list format.

Answer (score 0):

If your motivation is writing text lists you should check [vimwiki plugin](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki), saving vim format options for other uses, as coding.